# Reading large image using GDAL?

Tags: gdal, imagery, digital-image-processing

I want to read large image. The image size is 92117 x 30313 pixels. So far I know `cv2.imread` can not read large size.

How can I read using GDAL API?

Answer (score 4):

To read an image using `gdal` as a `numpy` array you can use the following two lines:

```
ds = gdal.Open('path_to_img', 0)
arr = ds.ReadAsArray()
```

However, you can run into a `MemoryError` if your image is too large. Depending on your needs, you can read one chunk of the image at the time. The [`ReadAsArray()`](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal_array-module.html#DatasetReadAsArray) method can take four useful arguments to accomplish this:

- `xoff`: offset to start reading the columns
- `yoff`: offset to start reading the rows
- `win_xsize`: number of columns to read
- `win_ysize`: number of rows to read

You can use two `for` loops to read the data in chunks. For example:

```
ds = gdal.Open('path_to_img', 0)
cols = ds.RasterXSize
rows = ds.RasterYSize
win_xsize = 100  # arbitrary value
win_ysize = 100  # arbitrary value

for i in range(0, rows, win_ysize):
    for j in range(0, cols, win_xsize):
        arr = ds.ReadAsArray(xoff=j, yoff=i, win_xsize=win_xsize, win_ysize=win_ysize)
```

Comment: Now win_xsize and win_ysize are simply xsize and ysize. All parameters:
https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-pysrc.html#Dataset.ReadAsArray

Still, your answer keep its value in methodology imo.